# ValueError: it Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: dataframe, python-2.7

I have a wine dataset which I'm analyzing. The response variable in the dataset is the wine quality. I visualized the relationship between other variables and the response variable using a boxplot, and there seemed to be a lot of outliers, So I was trying to distinguish the data with the outliers to decide on what to do with it, but the code keeps throwing an error, and i can't seem to fix it

```
`#Identifying outliers
features_to_investigate =['fixed_acidity', 'volatile_acidity', 'citric_acid', 'residual_sugar',
       'chlorides', 'free_sulfur_dioxide', 'total_sulfur_dioxide', 'density',
`       'ph', 'sulphates', 'alcohol']
`for feature in features_to_investigate:
    `q1 = wine.groupby('quality')[feature].quantile(0.25)`
   ``q3 = wine.groupby('quality')[feature].quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3-q1``
    
  ` lower_whisker = q1 - 1.5 * iqr`
    upper_whisker = q3 - 1.5 * iqr``

    #Identify potential outliers using Boolean indexing
    outliers = wine[(wine[feature] < ``lower_whisker`)` | `
                    (wine[feature] > upper_whisker)]
    `
    
    print(f"Potential Outliers in {feature}:")
outliers[['quality',feature]]`
```

This is the block of codes.